# Encoding of booleans in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

The encoding of booleans in pure lambda calculus:

true := λx.λy.x

false := λx.λy.y

cond := λb.λx.λy.b x y

So if "cond" re-defined as cond := λx.x and assume "true" and "false" are keep same as before, does this result in a valid encoding of booleans?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. The two definitions of `cond` are extensionally equal. But using the short version would make the definition even more mysterious, and it is very mysterious already.

You could also use $\lambda xy.xy$
or $\lambda abcd.abcd$ and it would work the same.

Some presentations omit `cond` completely and just say that the boolean value is itself the test.